# How to provision passwords on behalf of our organizations users without requiring OAuth authorization

Tags: java, google-admin-sdk

Under the now deprecated Google Apps Provisioning API, our organization was able to provision passwords on behalf of our users, simply by authorizing as a super admin user as follows:

```
 User userService = new UserService(GoogleAppsPasswordSyncConnector.class.getSimpleName());
 AuthTokenFactory authTokenFactory = AuthTokenFactoryThreadLocal.getAuthTokenFactory(adminUsername, adminPassword);
 userService.setAuthTokenFactory(authTokenFactory);
```

However, with the new Directory API, according to [Directory API: Authorize Requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing), requires that 'All requests to the Directory API must be authorized by an authenticated user.' And this is based on OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests.

How can we set passwords on behalf of our organizations users without requiring that they authorize the request?

Note that in some cases we may have in hand their current Google password, so that we might programmatically authorize on their behalf. However, for new Google accounts, we do not know the provisioned password.

Note that we utilize 'GADS' (Google Apps Directory Synch) in order to provision new Google accounts.

Answer (score 1):

After creating a Service Account type OAuth client id in the google developers console (https://console.developers.google.com/project) API's and Auth Credentials and enabling the Admin SDK in the API Project, and then adding the API scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user' to the scopes at https admin.google.com/AdminHome in Security 'Manage API Client access', I was able to set the password using the following code. Note that the account used to establish the above configuration has administrative rights to the Google emails in question.

```
        HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(clientEmail)
                .setServiceAccountUser(adminUser)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(privateKeyStoreLocation))
                .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).build();

        Directory directory = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, credential)
                .setApplicationName(applicationName)
                .build();

        Directory.Users.Get get = directory.users().get(userEmail);
        User user = get.execute();
        user.setPassword(newPassword);
        directory.users().patch(userEmail, user).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you look at it, you're going to have to authenticate with OAuth as you have linked. However, if you don't want to do the heavy lifting you may want to check out some other tools out there. If you're working in Windows in .Net/C# take a look at my project [gShell](https://github.com/squid808/gShell) which at it's most basic level is a [wrapper for the authentication in .Net](https://github.com/squid808/gShell/wiki/DotNet-Guide) but also provides PowerShell cmdlets that you can write scripts around.

In PowerShell, once you do the one-time authentication you can use [Set-GAUser](https://github.com/squid808/gShell/wiki/Set-GAUser) to update a user's password programatically like so:

```
Set-GAUser MyUser -NewPassword ThisIsTheNewPassword
```

Or you can have it generate one for you, if you'd prefer.

If you plan on using Python or would like to use the command line instead, check out [Google Apps Manager](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM) by [jay0lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1503886/jay-lee) which is also a wonderful resource.

As for the new accounts, you should be able to use GADS still for the new account and password creation. If you're not using it for the passwords, you should be able to use one of the above methods to tie in to your existing code.

Finally, if you're not using Windows as I have assumed here, both projects I mentioned are open source and you can browse the code for examples of how to authenticate, though the Google resources you have already found may be a little more straight-forward.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. Either way, you'll still need to authenticate and get the OAuth workflow going. Luckily the new APIs are all pretty similar it seems, so the code available from the two projects I mentioned may help you get in the right direction (maybe not). You may find use from their [Java quickstart documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/quickstart-java#step_3_set_up_the_sample) though. (For future questions, make sure to tag your post with the ```Java``` tag or whatever is appropriate so you'll get more targeted help!)

Comment: Java is our development platform of choice, and the one in which I will be building the password provisioning solution.

I'm still wondering whether the API requires the users current password in order to authorize the password change request (which I would programmatically execute on their behalf), or whether I might simply use some system level credentials (e.g. client id, client secret, system private key) for any user password change.

Comment: I've created a 'Service Account' credential, under Google's API's and Auth, in their developers console, and I'd like to be able to perform my password changes with these credentials alone.

Comment: I'm looking at building a GoogleCredential for this purpose:


`GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport)
                    .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                    .setServiceAccountId(clientId)
                    .setServiceAccountUser(clientEmail)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
                            new java.io.File(privateKeyStoreLocation))
                    .build();`

However, I'm not sure if this will achieve my goal.

Comment: I believe service accounts are usually used to access data through APIs on behalf of a user, for instance editing something in their drive or calendar. I'm pretty sure you wouldn't be able to use a service account to change passwords (since that is in the Admin SDK and requires admin rights, a user can't use the api to change their own password). As per [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount), "Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data."

Comment: This service account will have administrative access rights (I'm wanting it to at any rate). Will that not be sufficient to change the user's password? 

And, if not a service account, how then would an administrator account programmatically change a users Google password?

Comment: We need a programmatic solution that does not require user authorization of Google password change.